# Raspbian Desktop and Netcat script at boot

Tags: raspbian, boot, linux

I'm a complete beginner and I'm looking for some help.

I need to automatically start a command / script at boot to listen for a port from Netcat on computer with Raspbian Desktop version.

If I open the terminal from this computer and manually add the command like "nc -vklp 5555 | /bin/bash", it works fine and from another computer I can access and start a script, for example "echo sudo ./test.sh | nc 192.168.1.50 5555".

If instead I try to set the computer start listening to Netcat automatically at boot by modifying 'etc/rc.local" and adding "nc -vklp 5555 | /bin/bash" before "exit0", it doesn't work. Says port already in use and not working / not communicating. I have to disable it from "etc/rc.local".

Basically, I have to start Terminal and add the command manually to listen for Netcat otherwise it doesn't work.

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you !!!

Ps: apologize for my bad English

Comment: There are literally hundreds of questions explaining why rc.local is inappropriate on modern Linux and  (answers) suggesting alternatives.

Comment: Example https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/111846/8697

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between starting from rc.local and starting from command line is that you do not have the same PATH.
If nc is in /usr/bin then use /usr/bin/nc in your script.

Comment: Also the fact that rc.local runs BEFORE network is up